# C# - Class constants vs Enum - need as optional parameter and multiple same value for constants

Tags: c#, .net

I have a very tough problem that I don't really know if there is a solution that can fill all needs at the same time.
The three main requirements:

1. Possibility to store a value in a specific class or enum (not byte/int etc).
2. Multiple variables with the same value are available. Preferably having the possibility to get and compare it in a consistent way, otherwise having a default value that always output in a consistent way among all variables with the same value.
3. Have the possibility to put the variable in method parameter as optional. It is important because I use the variable ConstructorInfo that contains DefaultValue and handled dynamically.

First of all, I tried with an Enum.

```
public class Service
{
    public Response m_Response;

    public Service(Response response = Response.DEFAULT)
    {
        m_Response = response;
    }

    public enum Response : byte
    {
        DEFAULT = 0x00,
        SUCCESS = 0x00,
        UNSUPPORTED = 0x01
    }
}
```

With this example, I fill the need n°1 and 3. The problem is about n°2 because it is never consistent due to same value for multiple variables. If I do a test bench here:

```
[TestMethod]
public void test()
{
    Service.Response _default = Service.Response.DEFAULT; // 0
    Service.Response _success = Service.Response.SUCCESS; // 0
    Service.Response _unsupported = Service.Response.UNSUPPORTED; // 1

    string _default_str = _default.ToString();
    string _success_str = _success.ToString();
    string _unsupported_str = _unsupported.ToString();
}
```

The results are not consistent:

[result of tests with enum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLWlK.png)

As you can see, the debugger at first defines "Default" the value used by default, for both _default and _success variables. Furthermore, the ToString method returns another default value for both variables, but this time with "Success". And among all of this, there is no distinction between _default and _success, never. But for this one I think it's a normal behavior of an enum like this.

---

Then, I tried with class constants:

```
public class Service
{
    public Response m_Response;

    public Service(Response response = Response.DEFAULT)
    {
        m_Response = response;
    }

    public class Response
    {
        public const byte DEFAULT = 0x00;
        public const byte SUCCESS = 0x00;
        public const byte UNSUPPORTED = 0x01;
    }
}
```

First of all, **the line 5 is an error**. I put like this because I don't know if there is a mean to write it without compilation error.

With this example, I fill the need n°2 and a part of n°1. The problem is about n°3 because it looks like impossible to pass as an **optional** argument a constructor without using null.
The n°1 is also not really filled because to make it work in a simple way, I could replace `Response response =` for `byte response =` but I really need to restrict this var to a determined list of variables. Also, I would need a byte accessible variable to store the value that complexify the code a lot in comparison of the Enum solution

---

If you have any idea, don't hesitate. Thank you

Comment: How about using a dictionary to store what byte value each of the enum constants corresponds to. Then you can remove `byte` values from the enum, and they will all be distinct.

Comment: You mean something like `var Response = new Dictionary<string, byte>();` then `Response.Add("DEFAULT", 0x00); Response.Add("SUCCESS", 0x00); Response.Add("UNSUPPORTED", 0x01);` ? I was only working with static values, maybe that's why. I'll check if it fits. thanks. EDIT: I think it doesn't fit because I use the type of enum dynamically. Dic<x,y> cannot be discriminated by GetType()

Comment: Using string literals is kind of error prone. I'd recommend a `Dictionary<Response, byte>`, where `Response` is an enum that have constants with unique values.

Comment: Why must the values be same?

Comment: @Sweeper So it is not possible with static variables ? As I see the Response should be unique with this solution.
shingo due to standard. It can be dealt in 2 ways according to other fields (default for one, success or unsupported for another)

Comment: The DEFAULT const here is 0x00, but I need a "template" for dozen of other enum, which will have maybe the default value with another name and another value.

Comment: I don't get the "template" problem. Do you want to write a code generator to generate code for the different enums and therefore want a fixed name for different values?

Comment: I want to have the ability to write an enum that will be dealt dynamically afterwards with GetType. It was good until I wanted to get the enum default value (not consistent). To display it to the user (as wrote in the code). But when for example DEFAULT is set in code, the ToString method returns what it wants (like "SUCCESS"). At least I'm looking for a priority choice between all enum variable with the same value. The first post was to present all research I've done before posting

Comment: Then maybe the DefaultValue Attribute helps you in defining the default value for an enum instead of explicitly adding a Default value that collides with existing values. It needs some explicit code then to react to that attribute. But should be the same for all enums.

Comment: Is there a DefaultValue for Enum ?

Comment: DefaultValueAttribute is for every type. There is no actual behavior of the Framework attached to it (besides VS Designers). Actual behavior needs to be programmed by you. But its "generic" and can be used as "template" ignoring the concrete enum.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your requirements are that you expect a specific value to be convertible to multiple different strings. In your examples, what string does `0` represent? `SUCCESS`? `DEFAULT`? If they both have the same value *they are the same*.

If your source data is two different fields you could just keep the same model:

```
    public enum Response : byte
    {
        SUCCESS = 1, 
        UNSUPPORTED = 2,
    }
    public struct MyValue
    {
        public static readonly MyValue DEFAULT = new (true, Response.SUCCESS);
        public static readonly MyValue SUCCESS = new(false, Response.SUCCESS);
        public static readonly MyValue UNSUPPORTED = new(false, Response.UNSUPPORTED);
        public bool IsDefault { get; }
        public Response Response { get; }

        private MyValue(bool isDefault, Response response)
        {
            IsDefault = isDefault;
            Response = response;
        }
        public bool Equals(MyValue other)
        {
            if (IsDefault && other.IsDefault) return true;
            return  Response == other.Response;
        }
        public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is MyValue other && Equals(other);
        public override int GetHashCode() { unchecked { return (IsDefault.GetHashCode() * 397) ; } }
        public static bool operator ==(MyValue left, MyValue right) => left.Equals(right);
        public static bool operator !=(MyValue left, MyValue right) => !left.Equals(right);
        public override string ToString() => IsDefault ? "DEFAULT" : Response.ToString();
    }
```

This will not allow default optional parameter values, since the default value for the struct will be be an invalid value. The solution to this is to either use multiple overloads, or use a nullable parameter, i.e.

```
public void MyMethod(MyValue? v = default){
   var value = v ?? MyValue.DEFAULT;
   ...
}
```

Comment: To add some context, the Enum comes from a protocol standard that, according to others fields, can have different behavior. If the other field is 0x00, only DEFAULT should be used (that's why it is in optional parameter, to make it easier). If it's 0x01, only SUCCESS and UNSUPPORTED should be used. I cannot seperate in 2 enums because this field is still the same and existing, whatever the other field value.

It can be only enum > value. But the default value cannot be chosen as I saw among all enum variables of same values.

Comment: For the other solution, the problem is I show the enum list to the user with their value. So It has non-sense to display wrong values. (this is dynamically done whatever the enum selected)

Comment: @MartinP. Added example using two fields, If that is the format the protocol defines, it would most likely be easiest to keep the same model.